# Android: Generate a Mock Intent and return some intent-data from it

Tags: android, junit, mockito, easymock

I am using [ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html) for the unit testing of my application. I have a case where user clicks on a button of Activity 'A' and which in turns open a new Activity 'B' where user will do some work and finally some data is returned to Activity 'A' via setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

Now, i want to test this via jUnit and want to Mock this workflow so that no user interaction is required. Can someone help me with this.

PS: i dont want to use Robotium for this..i just want to do it via plain ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and some Mocking framework.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code to**

```
// Check the intent which was started
    Intent triggeredIntent = getStartedActivityIntent();
    assertNotNull("Intent was null", triggeredIntent);
    String data = triggeredIntent.getExtras().getString("URL");

//And

@Override 
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
        MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent, null, null);
    activity = getActivity();
  }
```

For details :: **[Follow this link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTesting/article.html)**

Comment: This code won't actually work in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 - you need ActivityUnitTestCase to for the getStartedActivityIntent() method.